# Using an array as a parameter in Haxe

Tags: haxe

I have a function that takes an array as a parameter, and it keeps returning the following error message:

```
Test.hx:34: characters 23-24 : Array<Int> should be { length : Void -> Int }
Test.hx:34: characters 23-24 : Invalid type for field length :
Test.hx:34: characters 23-24 : Int should be Void -> Int
Test.hx:34: characters 23-24 : For function argument 'array'
```

This is the code that produced the error message:

```haxe
class Test{
    static function main() {
        var a = new Array();
        a  = [1,2,3,4];
        enlarge1DArray(a); //why won't it work when I try to invoke this function?
    }

    static function enlarge1DArray(array){
        var i = 0;
        while(i < array.length()){
            i++;
            trace("i is " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `length` you are trying to access is a property, not a method. See the [Array API Documentation](https://api.haxe.org/Array.html#length).

Change the `while` line from this:

```
while(i < array.length())
```

to this:

```
while(i < array.length)
```

**Detailed Answer:**

The error you're getting is due to Haxe getting confused as it's guessing at the types. Basically, because you had were treating length as a method, it was assuming that the `array` parameter in the `enlarge1DArray` had to be some kind of object that had a method called length, with the type signature "Void->Int".

In short, because you were asking for a method, it was expecting the parameter "array" to have:

```
{ length : Void -> Int }
```

when an Array actually has:

```
{ length : Int }
```

So the compiler got confused and said you had your typing wrong.  You can read more about this on the Haxe wiki page for [Type Inference](http://haxe.org/ref/type_infer).  In future you can explicitly state what the types of each function parameter are, and then Haxe will give you more useful error messages.